# Can word break characters be changed in OS X 10.11 El Capitan (or Xcode 7.2)?

Tags: macos, xcode

When I double-click text in an Xcode string to select an entire word, any text connected to it with a dot (.) will also get selected. I would like to make that not happen so that dots and other characters behave as word break character, like dashes (-). Is there a way to change this either in general for OS X 10.11 or just specifically for Xcode 7.2?

I notice this happens in Xcode and in TextEdit so I'm guessing it would be an OS X setting, but then it doesn't happen when double-clicking on Xcode variables (only within strings) so I'm not sure.

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/125011/how-to-change-word-selection-separator-characters-in-mac-os-x